# Where is groups__name documented?

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

My Django app has several different types of users. For my Project model, I want to limit the pm column to User objects only belong to the 'Project Manager' group. After browsing through SE & googling around for a bit, I added the 'limit_choices_to' and assigned a Q object.

However, when I set up a TestCase that I was sure would fail, it seems any user can be added as a pm. Model and TestCase below:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    tracker = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
    pm = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', limit_choices_to=Q(groups__name = 'Project Manager'))


class ProjectTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.name = 'Crappy Project'
        self.tracker = 38493
        self.pm = User.objects.create_user('username', 'user@example.com', 'password')
        proj = Project.objects.create(name=self.name, tracker=self.tracker, pm=self.pm)
        proj.save()

    def test_proj_creation(self):       
        # Check stored values
        proj_zero = proj_in_db[0]
        self.assertEquals(proj_zero.name, self.name)
        self.assertEquals(proj_zero.pm, self.pm)
```

I'm trying to understand why my test keeps passing if I didn't assign the user to any group.  Also, where is 'groups__name' documented? I can't any reference to it in the Django docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groups__name` documentation is basically found as a combination of the [auth.User documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#methods) and the [fields lookup documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups), with the assumption you know that `auth.models.User` has a method `groups` that relates to `auth.models.Group`.

`limit_choices` only limits the choices available in the admin and (Model)forms; it doesn't limit the choices in the database, so any available choice can still be programmatically set; in your case, none at all (default). You could poke inside the database and see what it actually gives you for the `pm` field.

Comment: Your `limit_choices` explanation makes sense, thanks. I'm still not understanding how people are coming up with `groups__name`. It's not a field, and doing a `dir(User)` or `dir(Group)` doesn't list it as an attribute or property.

Comment: Read the [fields lookup documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) again: you can append two underscores with a lookup type to an attribute name; Django will dynamically take it apart and turn it into a proper query behind the scenes. Browse through all the little examples given in that documentation section (e.g., `headline__contains`, `name__iexact` etc).

Answer (score 0):

`limit_choices_to` only limits choices in `select`s in forms (in admin and in your own `ModelForm`s). In your code, you can still assign whoever you like.

The [`django.contrib.auth` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django-contrib-auth) covers the `User` and `Group` models and their fields.